# fpdf cell not dispaying correctly a concatenated php string

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I have a fdpf cell $DocRef->Cell(23,10,'Re: Patient: '.$patientdata,0,0,'L');

$patientdata is obtained from a mysql statement

if I use the following and place $patientdata in the above cell I get the desired result for example it will be displayed on the pdf document as Smith John Michael

```
 if (($uppatientID <> '') and ($uppatientID <> 0))
  {
    $patientsql =   "
      SELECT
        Concat_Ws(' ', `PatientLastName`, `PatientFirstName`, `PatientMiddleName`)
      FROM
        `Patient`
      Where
        `PatientID` = $uppatientID
    ";

    $patientresult=mysql_query ($patientsql) or die (mysql_error ());
    while ($patienttrow=mysql_fetch_row($patientresult))
      {
        $patientdata = $patienttrow[0];
      }
    mysql_free_result($patientresult);
   }
  else
    {
      $patientdata = ' ';
    }
```

Because the patient names are encrypted I need to do the following to decrypt them

```
if (($uppatientID <> '') and ($uppatientID <> 0))
  { 
    $patientsql =   "
      SELECT
        `PatientLastName`, `PatientFirstName`, `PatientMiddleName`
      FROM
        `Patient`
      Where
        `PatientID` = $uppatientID
    ";

    $patientresult=mysql_query ($patientsql) or die (mysql_error ());
    while ($patienttrow=mysql_fetch_row($patientresult))
      {
        $PatientLastNames = $patienttrow[0];
        $PatientFirstNames = $patienttrow[1];
        $PatientMiddleNames = $patienttrow[2];

        $patientdata = $PatientLastNames.$PatientFirstNames.$PatientMiddleNames;

      }
    mysql_free_result($patientresult);
   }
  else
    {
      $patientdata = ' ';
    }
```

but the cell above now displays them on the pdf document with a lot of white space between each name, this only happens when I join each string using php . to join them. Is there some formatting I can use to correct this.

Interestingly if I select the name on the pdf document and paste it then all the added white space is removed

Thanks,

Ivan

Comment: It doesn't look like the second example does anything to decrypt the patient names. What happens if you do a `var_dump()` on each of the variables? How long does it say the strings are? It may just be a matter of having to `trim()` each string individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference I can tell from your first and second method is the removal of white spacing in the $patientdata variable have you tried putting this back with php

```
$patientdata = $PatientLastNames." ".$PatientFirstNames." ".$PatientMiddleNames;
```

Comment: Why would *omitting* whitespace result in *more* whitespace?

Comment: No idea, If the first solution works then this would just be an equal result.

Comment: *"but the cell above now displays them on the pdf document with a lot of white space between each name,...*" Please re-read the question.

Comment: I understand that but if your not doing any additional code then there is no reason why these would not produce the same result.

Comment: If anything the fact he has not placed any spacing would cause additional issues with long strings forcing issues with cell width

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, you helped me to solve the problem.
Because I need to decrypt the table data they were padded with \u0000 to give a 32 character string. To remove this I needed to add str_replace("\x0", '', $str);

$patientdata = str_replace("\x0", '', PatientLastName . " " . PatientFirstName . " " . PatientMiddleName);

This now displays the pdf correctly